# New apk uploaded and getting “Supported devices 0” on my developer console

Tags: android, manifest, google-play

I have following code in my Manifest file.

```
<permission
    android:name="com.qpino.mobile.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.qpino.mobile.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!-- External storage for caching. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<!-- My Location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.qpino.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.qpino.mobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<!-- Permission to vibrate -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" /> -->
<!-- Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<!-- End of copy. -->

<application
    android:name="com.qpino.QpinoApplication"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/luncher_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBRl8oReRxt-njD9vATpw2r5DeCayidVaQ" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.ParentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.DataSafetyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CardFilterListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.BonusFilterListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.AnferdernActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.QpinoActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CouponActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.MyCardActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.BonusCardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CouponMapActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CouponDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CardDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.BonusDetailActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.StampActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CouponListingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.OptionActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.ProfilActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.WebViewActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.AccountActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CouponGroupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CardGroupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.BonusCardGroupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.OptionGroupActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CardMapActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.BonusMapActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.CouponFilterListActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.BarcodeActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.RecommendBonusActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.MyBonusCardActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.FavoriteCouponListingActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.RequestCardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.AllCardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.AddNewCardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.AddCustomCardActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.activities.MainTabActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.qpino.scanner.CaptureActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!--
            Allow web apps to launch Barcode Scanner by linking to
            http://zxing.appspot.com/scan.
        -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="zxing.appspot.com"
                android:path="/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- We also support a Google Product Search URL. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.google.com"
                android:path="/m/products/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- And the UK version. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.google.co.uk"
                android:path="/m/products/scan"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.qpino.scanner.PreferencesActivity" >
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.qpino.scanner.encode.EncodeActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This allows us to handle the Share button in Contacts. -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="text/x-vcard" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Receiver to receive push messages -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.qpino.mobile" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- Service to monitor push message received -->
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

I am not able to get any supported device.

Can anyone tell me what could be the issue ??

It would be a great help...

Regards,

Rakesh

Comment: anything to do with the version?

Answer (score 1):

I got that error once. I think what I did was I reverted back to the old version and re-upload the apk. If that doesn't work, Archive your current version and upload a new version - this will mean you will have to modify you app so that it's the next version up before you can upload a new apk.

Comment: I tried that , but still it is showing the same error. Can you please tell what could i do with new dashboard .. i checked my previous app and in none of them "Native platform"- junit-LICENSE.html , junit.jar was there but in the app i am uploading now i see this as a field.. But i am not sure how to remove this to have a look at what happens...

Comment: Sofry buddy, I don't know much about the dashboard, I only published one app so not much experience.

Comment: Thanks for your time... It was stupid mistake on the libraries we used in project.. Resolved on that that day itself.. Thanks once again..

Comment: Can you please explain your answer in detail, i am getting same error while using zxing library

Comment: @azzits there would be reference of some junit library inside the library you are using!!!! remove that and then the problem is solved

Comment: @RakeshGondaliya, yes i solved it by using updated library file